# Can I get the site owner value with workflow 2010?

Tags: workflow

I am using SP2013 standard. We don't install workflow 2013 so we are using the built-in workflow 2010 engine.

I need to build a workflow that will send email notification to site owner if an item have not been modified for 3 months.

In the Designer I can lookup for the item owner only. But I cannot pick site owner. Is there a way to lookup the site owner of the item? If possible I would like to avoid coding.

Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

The site owner can be found in the Site Owners SharePoint group. Add this group in the Email activity and the mail will be sent to all users who are in Site Owners group.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like you can. You have to specify the `group/person` that would happen to be the Site Owner.

For example. If you had an HR page and the Site Owner is the HR Site Owners Group, then in the workflow you would have to specify HR Site Owners Group.

This makes it a pain to create workflows form templates.